# how many topologies on a three element space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ be a three element set,
 - What are the total number of topologies that can be constructed on this set?
 - Not every collection of subsets  of $X$ is a topology on $X$.Why?

As i've just started topology,i do not have much comfortable setting for this. I need  help in understanding how  topologies are constructed on an any arbitrary set.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you try enumerating them? The number of topologies on an n-element set is an open problem in general. There is no way around brute forcing them and writing them out. The options are small enough in your case that it is fairly straightforward.

Comment: By the way to make $\{$ and $\}$ render in $\rm\LaTeX$, do \{ and \} inside the $.

Comment: @CameronWilliams:yeah,i tried it ,first by considering the  number of subsets of X,then by permuting these subsets, but i'm not getting the exact answer

Comment: @CameronWilliams The article [Wikipedia: Finite topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space) has some information. In an example they mention that the above $X$ has 29 possible topologies ($X$ has $2^3=8$ subsets, so there are $2^8=256$ collection os subsets, and 29 of those are topologies). Up to homeomorphism there are 9 topological spaces with three points.

Comment: Have a look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32153/alternative-definition-for-topological-spaces?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the following class of subsets of $X$:
$$\mathcal{F}=\lbrace  \lbrace a \rbrace, \lbrace b\rbrace, \lbrace c\rbrace , X , \emptyset\rbrace.$$ This class of set isn't a topology on $X$, infact $\lbrace a \rbrace \cup\lbrace b \rbrace= \lbrace a,b\rbrace\not\in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: :THANKs,I got it.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a topology on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following three properties:

1. The sets $\varnothing$ and $X$ are members of the collection.
2. The intersection of finitely many members is a member.
3. The union of an arbitrary subcollection of members is a member.

There are literally only $8$ subsets of $X$ in your case, and you know any topology must already contain $2$ of them. So just try adding in other subsets, making sure that the above three properties are satisfied, and use symmetry to make life easier...

Comment: :Is there any way so that i get the intuition for this?